# Stand Alone Installer for Smartface App Studio?

Tags: smartface.io

my internet connection speed is slow so I need download stand alone installer of Smartface App Studio. Is there any link? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Smartface 4.4.0 from the link below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9w13jl99d95ryor/SmartfaceAppStudio.exe?dl=0

Run this exe, and setup will be installed.

New version of Smartface App Studio(4.5.0) will be released at the end of this week.